How do I store data returned by a Rust callback?
New to Rust - not sure "callback" is the right terminology. Here is a slimmed down version of the code I am trying to write based on a crate I am using:
struct Thing {}

trait CrateSuppliedTrait {
    fn start_handling() where {
        // Pretend this is actually implemented by the Crate and
        // starts a long running process...
    }
    fn handle(
        &mut self,
        thing: &mut Thing
    );
}

struct MyHandler<'a> {
    things: Vec<&'a mut Thing>,
}

impl<'a> CrateSuppliedTrait for MyHandler<'a> {
    // Called every time there is something to handle
    fn handle(
        &mut self,
        thing: &mut Thing // Crate implements code that calls this handle method and returns this
    ) {
        // What is the right way to store this data?
        // It doesn't compile due to "lifetime may not live long enough".
        self.things.push(thing);
    }
}

fn main() {
    MyHandler::start_handling();
}

I would like to take the "Thing" that is returned as a mutable reference and store it in memory for an indefinite amount of time. What is the best approach for doing this?
The code above gives me the error:
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:23:9
   |
15 | impl<'a> CrateSuppliedTrait for MyHandler<'a> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
19 |         thing: &mut Thing // Crate implements code that calls this handle method and returns this
   |                - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
23 |         self.things.push(thing);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'a`

error: could not compile `playground` (bin "playground") due to 1 previous error


An empty where clause is a new thing...

Ya, I added that to get my example code to compile further - IRL the crate I linked implements an actual function rather than that.

The correct fix depends on what precisely you want to do with the handler, but it may look like this.

Well, yup that compiles - thanks. So basically at an undefined point in time in the future I want to be able to do something with the Vec<&'a mut Thing> - in the actual case it is video frames that I want to send to an encoder to create a video file. The repo I linked shows an example of how to do this as video is being captured - but I want to wait to do it until the user does some interaction and/or a certain amount of time has gone by...if that makes sense.

Those vague words don't help me. Please describe what you want to do with them in code, exact code that you want to compile (and doesn't currently).

I think your first code snippet moves me along in the right direction. I suppose it illustrates my lack of understanding with lifetimes in rust. I'll look more into that and see if I can get further with my actual code later. Thank you!
